# multiple rows mysqrl syntax error

Tags: mysql

I have looked and tested alot things to find a solution for my issue... 
I am using mysqrl 5.0!
I insert multiple rows with this:

insert into test_table (id,code)
values ('id','my code'),
       ('id','my code'),
       ('id','my code'),
       ('id','my code');

This works for most information, but I am actually inserting a large line of code into the mysqrl database, this code calls an image with a bunch of features.  I have no problems doing it manually 1 at a time with an html form, but I want to be able to dump a bunch at 1 time...  my code I use looks like this:

```
 <a class="btn"><img src="http://mywebsite.com/images/lmo/99.png" title="" onmouseover="this.src='https://myimage.imageshack.us/v2/128x128q90/839/nmfe.jpg'"onmouseout="this.src='http://mywebsite.com/images/lmo/99.png'" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('f1').value+='0359F3E4-8FEE44E2-850C66D0-4A14725E\n';">
```

When I enter this into an insert.php it gives a syntax error because of it being code...  In the table I only have 2 columns: (id),(my code)... I know this is probably a very unusual question but Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank You...

Comment: use prepared statements or at least escape special chars like `'` properly